# Как правильно использовать кастомный селект в проекте с Vue.js, чтобы Vue реагировал на изменение селекта?

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, form, select

Есть свой селект, который скрывает стандартный селект и поверх него делает кастомный, хотел засунуть его в проект с Vue, чтобы не переделывать его:

```
<select name="nationality" v-model="national">
   <option value="russia">Российская федерация</option>
   <option value="belarus">Беларусь</option>
   <option value="ukraine">Украина</option>
   <option value="kazakhstan">Казахстан</option>
</select>



var $this = $(this), numberOfOptions = $(this).children('option').length;

    $this.addClass('select-hidden');
    $this.wrap('<div class="select"></div>');
    $this.after('<div class="select-styled"></div>');

    var $styledSelect = $this.next('div.select-styled');
    $styledSelect.text($this.children('option').eq(0).text());

    var $list = $('<ul />', {
      'class': 'select-options'
    }).insertAfter($styledSelect);

    for (var i = 0; i < numberOfOptions; i++) {
      $('<li />', {
        text: $this.children('option').eq(i).text(),
        rel: $this.children('option').eq(i).val()
      }).appendTo($list);
    }

    var $listItems = $list.children('li');

    $styledSelect.click(function(e) {
      e.stopPropagation();
      $('div.select-styled.active').not(this).each(function(){
        $(this).removeClass('active').next('ul.select-options').hide();
      });
      $(this).toggleClass('active').next('ul.select-options').toggle();
    });

    $listItems.click(function(e) {
      e.stopPropagation();
      $styledSelect.text($(this).text()).removeClass('active');
      $styledSelect.attr('rel', $(this).attr('rel'));
      $this.val($(this).attr('rel'));
      $list.hide();
      $this.trigger('changed');
    });

    $(document).click(function() {
      $styledSelect.removeClass('active');
      $list.hide();
    });
  });
```

В обычном селекте все норм меняется в Vue, но не понимаю как отслеживать изменение в кастомном селекте. У меня в html-коде кастомного селекта нет. В html у меня селект стандартный, а при помощи скрипта и стилей создается кастомный в DOM. Получается, что на дивы от кастомного селекта нельзя ничего повесить в html.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы хотите обернуть во что-то стандартный селект и скрыть логику - то создайте обёртку в виде компонента Vue, в котором вы проведёте все изменения явно без использования jq, после чего используйте созданный компонент в проекте вместо стандартного селекта.